# Potential problems with skipMemoryCache() in Picasso?

Tags: android, image, caching, out-of-memory, picasso

I have a main `DashboardActivity` that uses a REST client to grab photos from a staging server. I found that when I would load the `Bitmap` from the server into an `ImageButton` it would throw a `OutOfMemoryError`. I solved this issue with using `.skipMemoryCache()` like so:

```
Picasso.with(this)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .skipMemoryCache()
       .into(imageButton);
```

What would be some potential problems I would run into with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `skipMemoryCache` now, because it is deprecated. [Here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/526) is some discussion about this method. Instead of using `skipMemoryCache` you should use `memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy policy, MemoryPolicy... additional)`.

Comment: I'm aware of this now, since I posted this in Feb., could you tell me what performance issues / improvements, user experience issues / improvements that might have?

Comment: nice one, this help us a lot.